# What are these games?

Tags: identify-this-game

What are the three games seen above and to the right of Tom Vasel, between Twilight Struggle and Goa? Looks like a series called Ancients or with "Ancients" in the title.

[image: ancients?]

Comment: What is the source of this picture?

Comment: @murgatroid99 not the same source but  @0:23 you can see what looks like the same games on right side http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv-sVB5EBGo

Comment: @ColinD - The games behind the person are different in the OP's still picture vs. the video frame you cite. The position of GOA is changed, and Agricola is in the video but not the OP's picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like games from the "[Commands and Colors: Ancients](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/14105/commands-colors-ancients)" series.

I would assume that one is the [base game](http://www.gmtgames.com/p-499-commands-colors-ancients-5th-printing.aspx) and the other two are expansions, likely [Rome vs. Barbarians](http://www.gmtgames.com/p-338-c-c-ancients-exp-combo-pack-2-3-reprint-editions.aspx) and [Roman Civil War](http://www.gmtgames.com/p-338-c-c-ancients-exp-combo-pack-2-3-reprint-editions.aspx)

Comment: You can see the side of the box of the base game [here](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1099868/commands-colors-ancients?size=original) (Warning: large image)

Comment: @ikegami That page requires a login. Can you rehost the image?

Comment: @murgatroid99, You should be able to see the [scaled-down version](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/1099868/commands-colors-ancients). If not, let's just say it confirms My Turn Yet's answer.